# Passing certificate and key as string to ListenAndServeTLS

Tags: security, go

I am creating an app using Go and I am trying to start a https server using the `ListenAndServeTLS` function. Here is my code:

```
func StartServer() {
    defer config.CapturePanic()
    c := config.GetInstance()

    serverAddress := fmt.Sprintf(":%s", c.GetConfig().ServerPort)
    server := http.Server{Addr: serverAddress}

    log.Info("Starting local server")
    http.HandleFunc("/", login.Handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/login", login.Handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/settings", settings.Handler)

    //cert, _ := data.Asset("my-cert.pem")
    //key, _ := data.Asset("my-key.pem")
    err := server.ListenAndServeTLS("my-cert.crt", "my-cert.key")
    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Fatal("Error stopping local server")
    }
}
```

The thing is that I would like to embed my certificate and its key inside my executable file and then pass them to the the `server.ListeAndServeTLS` function as a string or a byte array. However this function does not take these types of arguments. Is there another way to do this?

Note: I am aware that it is a bad practice to embed a private key inside a client application, however what I am trying to do here is just to create a config webpage that will be hosted as `https://localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can build your own server object and still call `ListenAndServeTLS`. Since your tls config has certificates, it will ignore the passed-in filenames.
I'm omitting the return on error for conciseness, please do not:

```
// Generate a key pair from your pem-encoded cert and key ([]byte).
cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(<cert contents>, <key contents>)

// Construct a tls.config
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
  Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}
  // Other options
}

// Build a server:
server := http.Server{
    // Other options
    TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
}

// Finally: serve.
err = server.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I changed my code to your suggestion, but the `tls.Loadx509KeyPair()` function also expects a path to a certificate file and a path to a key file and not a byte array containing this information. When I ran your code I got this error: `open : The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Good point. I've edited the answer to use `tls.X509KeyPair`. In the future, you can just look at the source of [Loadx509KeyPair](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/tls.go?s=5407:5474#L168) and see what it does.

Comment: Hi, I changed to use the `tls.X509KeyPair` and everything works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was unable to load files from disk, but did have the certificates passed in to the environment as variables (`[]byte`).

Adding on to Marc's answer, I had to only change the top line.

```golang
// Append signed leaf certificate and intermediate to a single  
certChain := append(leaf.PublicBytes, intermediate.PublicBytes...)

// Generate a key pair from your pem-encoded cert and key ([]byte).
cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(certChain, leaf.PrivateBytes)
...
```